# Print API response in "Test results" tab in Postman

Tags: automated-testing, postman

I'm using Postman to automate an API using Newman.

But the response body of the API call is not showing in the Postman "Test results" tab.

```
var body = JSON.parse(responseBody); 
tests["Response Body ", body] = true;
```

I have tried the above code,but even after successful API call the response is not printing in the "Test results" tab.

The output of above is showing as,
     PASS [object Object]

Any suggestions to print the API response will be of great help.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried a console.log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try without parsing, Like below

```
var body = JSON.parse(responseBody); 
var content = responseBody;
tests["Response Body"+content]= body.length != 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than reinvent the wheel, if you're implementing that then there is a lovely graphical HTML report you can tag onto newman that just does all that for you (newman-reporter-htmlextra).

It auto records the headers / body / etc of the requests and responses. It also helps with providing a "management" friendly colourful report of the results.

You just need to install it into Node.js then add on a switch in the newman call.

e.g.

```
newman run myFile.json -e environment.json --reporters htmlextra --reporter-htmlextra-export reportfilelocation.htm
```